# Objectbox inherit properties from base class (which is NOT an entity itself)

Tags: java, objectbox

I have a simple base class in which I want to have some common fields, like id etc. The base class is not an Entity by itself.

```
public class Base {

    @Id
    protected long id;

    protected String someOtherCommonProperty;
}
```

And I have an entity class, extending the base class.

```
@Entity
public class Entity extends Base {

    String name;
    String address;
}
```

I would expect the entity class to inherit the fields from the base class, but what I get is

```
[ObjectBox] No @Id property found for 'Entity', add @Id on a not-null long property.
```

Is there any way to fix that, besides using interfaces and have a lot of duplicated code?

Comment: The example Entity does not extend Base, though I'm sure yours does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@BaseEntity` annotation.
Have a look at the documentation: [Objectbox - Entity Inheritence](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/entity-inheritance).

Shameless copy for future reference:

---

> In addition to the `@Entity`  annotation, we introduced a `@BaseEntity`  annotation for base classes, which can be used instead of `@Entity`.
> There three types of base classes, which are defined via annotations:

- No annotation: The base class and its properties are not considered for persistence.
- `@BaseEntity`: Properties are considered for persistence in sub classes, but the base class itself cannot be persisted.
- `@Entity`: Properties are considered for persistence in sub classes, and the base class itself is a normally persisted entity.

---

Example:

```java
    // base class:
    @BaseEntity
    public abstract class Base {
        
        @Id long id;
        String baseString;
        
        public Base() {
        }
        
        public Base(long id, String baseString) {
            this.id = id;
            this.baseString = baseString;
        }
    }
    
    // sub class:
    @Entity
    public class Sub extends Base {
        
        String subString;
        
        public Sub() {
        }
        
        public Sub(long id, String baseString, String subString) {
            super(id, baseString);
            this.subString = subString;
        }
    }
```